# Metal Shading Language - buffer binding

Tags: kernel, macos-sierra, metal

I want to have particles that will increase at time. I got [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571708/metal-shading-language-change-buffer-size?rq=1) that set the buffer value higher so that I can play around with the amount of the particles. what I am thinking is I will have a maximum count size set to the buffer, then in `shader`, I will have a `struct` with array to take the particles attribute.

I have this in my `swift`:

```
var vectMaxCount = 10
var metalvects = [float3(0.0,0.0,0.0),float3(1.0,0.0,0.0),float3(2.0,0.0,0.0)]
var vectBuffer: MTLBuffer!
```

Then I register the `buffer`:

```
vectBuffer  = device!.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<float3>.size * vectMaxCount, options: [])
```

and update the `buffer` accordingly:

```
...
command_encoder.setBuffer(vectBuffer, offset: 0, at: 2)
var bufferPointer = vectBuffer.contents()
memcpy(bufferPointer, &metalvects, MemoryLayout<float3>.size * vectMaxCount)

let threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(8, 8, 1)
let threadGroups = MTLSizeMake(drawable.texture.width / threadGroupCount.width, drawable.texture.height / threadGroupCount.height, 1)
command_encoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount)
command_encoder.endEncoding()
command_buffer.present(drawable)
command_buffer.commit()
```

and try to get it from `metal` file:

```
struct Vects
{
    float3 position[100];
};

kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                    constant Vects &vects [[buffer(2)]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
...
}
```

and I got an error:

> validateComputeFunctionArguments:727: failed assertion `(length -
>   offset)(160) must be >= 1600 at buffer binding at index 2 for
>   vects[0].'

It is indicated the line `command_encoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount)` give me error. I read a bit about `buffer binding` and I think is the way I send the `threadGroupCounts` or `ThreadGroup` that give me issue.

If I change `float3 position[100];` to `float3 position[7];`, it still work. Anything more then 7 will get the similar error.

How can I resolve this?

And is there a good formula to estimate `threadGroups` and `threadGroupCount`? Even rule of thumb to do that?

**Update01**

Based on Ken Thomases's answer, I change my code to:

swift:

```
vectBuffer  = device!.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<float3>.stride * metalvects.count, options: [])
...
memcpy(bufferPointer, &metalvects, MemoryLayout<float3>.stride * metalvects.count)
...
```

metal:

```
struct Vects
{
    float3 position[3];
};
...
```

It does work for now. But how can I allocate higher buffer memory that yet to be used later in the app like  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571708/metal-shading-language-change-buffer-size?rq=1) mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

You are defining `Vects` with a specific size. That allows Metal to check if the size of the buffer at index 2 is big enough to match the size of your `vects` variable. It is complaining because it isn't big enough. (It wouldn't be able to do this check if `vects` were declared as `constant float3 *vects [[buffer(2)]]`, for example.)

Second, the size of your buffer — `MemoryLayout<float3>.size * vectMaxCount` — is incorrect. It fails to take into account the alignment of `float3` and therefore the padding that exists between elements in your `[float3]` array. As noted in the [documentation for `MemoryLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/memorylayout), you should always use `stride`, not `size`, when calculating allocation sizes.

This is why the failure happens when `Vects::position` is 8 or more elements long. You would expect it to start at 11 elements because `vectMaxCount` is 10, but your buffer is shorter than an array of `vectMaxCount` `float3`s. To be specific, your buffer is 10 * 12 == 120 bytes long. The stride of `float3` is 16 and 120 / 16 == 7.5.

If you switch from `size` to `stride` when allocating your buffer and change the element count of `Vects::position` to 10 to match `vectMaxCount`, then you'll get past this immediate issue. However, there are additional problems lurking.

Your compute function as it currently stands doesn't know how many elements of `vects.position` are actually filled. You need to pass in the actual count of elements.

This line:

```
memcpy(bufferPointer, &metalvects, MemoryLayout<float3>.size * vectMaxCount)
```

is incorrect (even after replacing `size` with `stride`). It reads past the end of `metalvects`. That's because the number of elements in `metalvects` is less than `vectMaxCount`. You should use `metalvects.count` instead of `vectMaxCount`.

Comment: Please check update01. I am took reference from another post you answered.

Comment: You can and should keep using `vextMaxCount` when *allocating* the buffer. It's just the call to `memcpy()` where you should use `metalvects.count`.

Comment: Yup, it works. I need to read more about the `Memory Layout` and such. Do you have any good recommendations?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.